# Typescript: Interface Type as constant in another class

Tags: typescript, react-native, interface

I had created interface and use that in Function component.
I want to use that function component into another class by using type or constant.

Below is code for Class A:

```
export interface InterfaceProps {
  someFunction1(): Promise<boolean>;
}

export const ClassA: InterfaceProps {
 async someFunction1(): Promise<boolean> {
 }

 async someFunction2(): Promise<boolean> {
 }
}
```

Below is code for Class B:

```
import React, {FC} from 'react';

 const ClassB: FC<> = ({}) => {
      const interfaceConstClassA = InterfaceProps or ClassA// want to use InterfaceProps as constant so

        return (
         <Button
              title='Test'
              onPress={async () => {
                const resultBoolean: boolean = await ClassA.someFunction1(); // Want to write interfaceConstClassA instead of ClassA.someFunction1();
                console.log("Class called");
              }}
            />);
    }
```

This is working good. But i want to create constant for classAinterface in classB .
So instead of referring to concrete class i want to write interface Type as constant.
This will help when i write the UnitTest i will create fakeclass and replace the constant.

Comment: Does this question depend on React (or whatever `FC` is)? If so you might want to tag it as such to get the right eyes on it.  If not you should remove the code's dependency on it so it's a self-contained [mre].

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What would it even do?

Comment: I want to write the constant so that i can override the methods/class in future for test

Comment: If it depends on React, it should be *tagged* as such. I can edit the tag for you if you want.  Also, please make sure your code is a [mre] that demonstrates what you're talking about when others paste it into their own IDEs.  Your code has syntax errors (is `ClassA` supposed to be a class or something? etc) and missing definitions (`NavigationProp` etc).  Right now it's not in a state I'm comfortable touching.